# How do I clean this ugly piece of Scala code

Tags: scala, monads

This is a really simple use case but I don't find any elegent way to handle it.

Below what I'm trying to do. It's pretty explicit...

**Note:** `users.byEmail` return a `Future[Option[User]]`.

```
override def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: UserRequest[A] => Future[Result]): Future[Result] = {
  val useEmail: Option[String] = request.session.get("userEmail")
  if (useEmail.isEmpty) {
    return Future.successful(Results.Unauthorized(("No email")))
  }
  val user: Option[User] = Await.result(users.byEmail(useEmail.get), Duration(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES))
  if (user.isEmpty) {
    return Future.successful(Results.Unauthorized(("No user")))
  }
  block(UserRequest(user.get, request))
}
```

What is the "correct" way to write this ?

Comment: On mobile, so I can not provide all the code but. I would pattern match on the first and second option. Use `flatMap` instead of **awaiting** the future of `user.byemail` and remove all the `return`, hope that hepls you refactor the code. - BTW, IMHO, all those steps should be _"obvious"_ for any _"junior"_ Scala programmer, I would advice you to follow some tutorial or read some book about the language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a cleaner version:

```
def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: UserRequest[A] => Future[Result]): Future[Result] =
  request.session.get("userEmail") match {
    case None =>
      Future.successful(Results.Unauthorized(("No email")))
    case Some(useEmail) =>
      users.byEmail(useEmail).flatMap {
        case None =>
          Future.successful(Results.Unauthorized("No user"))
        case Some(user) =>
          block(UserRequest(user, request))
      }
  }
```

The key changes are

Use `match` rather than `if` on `Option` class

Don't use `return`, this is rarely necessary and may not do what you think it does

Use `flatMap` on the `Future` rather than `Await.result` to avoid blocking

Comment: Clearly better but if I have a lot of instructions, I will end with a lot of indentation. Is there any way to fix it ?

Comment: The best way is for each step to generate Future.failed on error, rather than Future.successful. Then you can chain a list of operations using `flatMap` or `for`